# Use a user model in a custom authentification in Cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using a custom authentification object in cakephp.

```
In AppController :
$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Ldap','Database');
```

I need my custom auth component to connect to the database.
I have created the file DatabaseAuthenticate in Controller/Component/Auth/DatabaseAuthentification.php
In my custom object I need to request a table in my database. I have tried some function than a controller

```
public $uses =array('Car', 'Bike');
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cakephp2? you could try:

```
$model = ClassRegistry::init('Yourmodel');
```

Simple query with your model into your component

```
$result= $model->find('all');
```